# How can you use a phonenumber assigned to SIP with SMS

Tags: twilio

Need to know if Twilio can use the same numbers used for SIP trunks to be used for SMS? If not what is the best work around?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need a number that can support both voice and messaging, but when you have one of those you can configure the voice side of things with a SIP trunk and the SMS side of things with a webhook/Studio Flow/Twilio Function or whatever you like.

Note: SIP does not concern itself with SMS, so you will need to handle SMS differently to voice calls.